# Download a file onclick doesn't work

Tags: html

This is insane. Redirecting to a page on button click works perfectly but when I try to create download on button click for my app on my website it just redirects me to the error site.

```
<input onclick="window.open('application/application.apk')" 
title="Download App" value="Download App" name="fSubmit" id="fSubmit" 
type="button"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

what is http error code or message???
for example the "apk" extension in iis is not defined in popular mime-type and you can not request this file directly. if you use iis add "apk" to mime-type list.

Comment: error404. I'm hosting my own domain in 000webhost servers if that helps anyhow.

Comment: you can in web control panel add this extension to mime-types.

Comment: I've added line "AddType application/vnd.android.package-archive .apk" to htaccess - still the same error OR it's a wrong phrase i've been thinking of

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<a href="application/application.apk" target="_blank" download><button title="Download App" value="Download App" name="fSubmit" id="fSubmit" >Download App</button></a>
```

Comment: This code destroys my button's appearance and it's not working. error404 like before

Comment: `<a href="test.apk" download><input onclick="window.open()" 
title="Download App" value="Download App" name="fSubmit" id="fSubmit" 
type="button"/></a>`      doesn't works in IE or old browsers